# How do I retrieve all the descendant text nodes under an ancestor element as a single string?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a set of xml files with strings of text enclosed by elements and then subdivided by other elements. For example,

```
<a>rhino<b>c<c>er</c></b>os</a>
```

`<a>` contains a single word, with sets of characters within that word marked up for various reasons. However, I want to be able to write a query that retrieves the whole word, that is, the text string in `<a>` without spaces or any trace that some of the text comes from descendant elements at all (in the example, the result should be "rhinoceros").

How do I do this? I have researched multiple methods for retrieving descendant text nodes but these all ultimately result in either some of the desired word being omitted or, at best (" //w/descendant-or-self::*/text() "), all text nodes being retrieved but as different search results.

I am still a beginner at all things xml, so apologies if I am asking something quite basic. I am happy to take reading recommendations in lieu of a straightforward answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have XPath 2.0, use

```
string-join(//text(), '')
```

on the XML

```
<a>rhino<b>c<c>er</c></b>os</a>
```

It selects all text nodes and concatenates them without spaces.

Try it on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of XPath and XPath-based languages!

The `string()` function may be the most direct route to achieving your goal. It returns the string value of the item provided as its argument, so:

```
string(<a>rhino<b>c<c>er</c></b>os</a>)
```

... will return:

```
rhinoceros
```

See the XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators specification for this function:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string

Comment: Also worth pointing out that in many contexts the `string()` function is applied automatically, for example `//a[contains(., 'ceros')]` will select this element.